# How to use x:bind inside ControlTemplate in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Hi I was just trying to use x:Bind in ControlTemplate of Button in UWP my simple code is below,

```
<Grid>
<TextBox x:Name="txtWidth"/>       
    <Button x:Name="btnEllipse" PointerEntered="btnEllipse_PointerEntered" PointerExited="btnEllipse_PointerExited" Click="btnEllipse_Click">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Ellipse x:Name="myEll" Width="{x:Bind  ShapeWidth,Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding Width,ElementName=myEll}" Fill="Purple" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

C# Code behind file

```
double _shapeWidth= 100;
    public Double ShapeWidth
    {
        get { return _shapeWidth; }
        set { _shapeWidth = value; }
    }
```

I am getting error that
***target type' is required to use x:Bind inside a ControlTemplate***
Please let me know where I am making mistake,?

***Another scenario can we bind txtWidth using Binding or x:Bind in Ellipse Width here?***

Comment: Hi, can the following method help? Do you have other questions?

Comment: Hi Faywang both methods works for me thanks for your help,I have marked as answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/templatebinding-markup-extension#xbind-in-controltemplate), when you try to use x:bind in ControlTemplate, you need to add the **TargetType** property(e.g. `<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">`). However, The function of x:bind is like TemplateBinding, it can only bind with the property of Button, so if you want to bind with the property which declared in code-behind, it's better to use **Binding** and declare the **DataContext**. For example:

.xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="btnEllipse"  PointerExited="btnEllipse_PointerExited" Click="btnEllipse_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Ellipse x:Name="myEll" Width="{Binding ShapeWidth}" Height="{Binding Width,ElementName=myEll}" Fill="Purple" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

.cs:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

> Another scenario can we bind txtWidth using Binding or x:Bind in
> Ellipse Width here?

If you want to bind the width of txtWidth with the width of Ellipse, you could use ElementName to find the txtWidth element and use binding to bind with its width.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtWidth" Width="100" Text="efwiehfiweh"/>
<Button x:Name="btnEllipse"  PointerExited="btnEllipse_PointerExited" Click="btnEllipse_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Ellipse x:Name="myEll" Width="{Binding Width,ElementName=txtWidth,Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding Width,ElementName=myEll}" Fill="Purple" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```